# Problems with the script in Google Collab

Tags: python

I use this script https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z31ZfcisCXCSGA5jeid0UNjiHb9oupuV#scrollTo=b-4eVF_7T_YF
And when I go to Setup1 there are some errors:

```
Downloading pyworld-0.3.0.tar.gz (212 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 212.0/212.0 kB 12.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/, https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

Then:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchvision 0.15.1+cu118 requires torch==2.0.0, but you have torch 1.13.1+cu116 which is incompatible.
torchtext 0.15.1 requires torch==2.0.0, but you have torch 1.13.1+cu116 which is incompatible.
torchdata 0.6.0 requires torch==2.0.0, but you have torch 1.13.1+cu116 which is incompatible.
torchaudio 2.0.1+cu118 requires torch==2.0.0, but you have torch 1.13.1+cu116 which is incompatible.
```

And then:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-metadata 1.13.1 requires protobuf<5,>=3.20.3, but you have protobuf 3.19.6 which is incompatible.
onnx 1.13.1 requires protobuf<4,>=3.20.2, but you have protobuf 3.19.6 which is incompatible.
```

I tried:

```
!pip install torch==2.0
!pip install protobuf=3.20.2
```

And more..

Comment: Have you corrected the issues flagged? like updating torch from version 1.13 to version2 as it tells you?

Comment: @SolarMike yeah I just did !python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip torch==2.0 and there's what I got ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. torchaudio 0.13.1+cu116 requires torch==1.13.1, but you have torch 2.0.0 which is incompatible.